# Show / Hide href link

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am working on a web application. I have 4 a href menus (Eg.- Menu1 Menu2 Manu3 Menu4 ). I want to check the condition if customer is free then the menu "Menu4" should be invisible and if customer is paid then they can access or see all above menus (Eg.- Menu1 Menu2 Manu3 Menu4).

Comment: This is pretty basic. Just check account level on backend, runa case statement and viola. Any code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You should have the customer's status either in a Session or Get parameter, and then set the menu's CSS to "visibility: visible;" or "visibility: hidden;".

Answer (score 1):

If your links are server side, you can set their visible property as true or false. Please check that link [HyperLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx)

Comment: Probably there are another answers but I can suggest you a server side panel that contains your href link. You can change panels visibility and inherently show or hide link.

<asp:Panel ID="pnlHref" runat="server">
 <a href="Test.aspx">Test Link</a>
</asp:Panel>

Comment: I have all 4 menu in a DIV and I want to hide and show the last manu Menu4 with some conditions.

Comment: Ok, can you replace Menu4 into Panel? So you can hide or show it.